Where to set the scheduler and sampler?
If I'm trying to build an inferencer using Python and the huggingface library, where do I set the scheduler and sampler? What function do I call? For context, this is what my code looks like:
import torch, PIL, random

from typing import List, Optional, Union
from diffusers import StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline

device = "cuda"
# pipeline = StableDiffusionXLPipeline.from_single_file("/content/models/juggernautXL_version2.safetensors", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True, safety_checker=None ).to("cuda")
model_path = "runwayml/stable-diffusion-inpainting"

pipe = StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline.from_pretrained(model_path,torch_dtype=torch.float16,).to(device)

def image_grid(imgs, rows, cols):
    assert len(imgs) == rows*cols

    w, h = imgs[0].size
    grid = PIL.Image.new('RGB', size=(cols*w, rows*h))
    grid_w, grid_h = grid.size

    for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
        grid.paste(img, box=(i%cols*w, i//cols*h))
    return grid


def present_img(url):
    return PIL.Image.open(url)

mask_url = "masks/mask_PXL_20240419_181351038.MP.jpg.png"
img_url = "originals/PXL_20240419_181351038.MP.jpg"

image = present_img(img_url).resize((512, 512))
mask_image = present_img(mask_url).resize((512, 512))

prompt = "car on a desert highway. Detailed. High resolution. Photorealistic. Soft light."

guidance_scale=7.5
num_samples = 3
generator = torch.Generator(device="cuda").manual_seed(random.randint(0,1000)) # change the seed to get different results

# Assuming 'image' and 'mask_image' are predefined Image objects
images = pipe(
    prompt=prompt,
    image=image,
    mask_image=mask_image,
    guidance_scale=guidance_scale,
    generator=generator,
    num_images_per_prompt=num_samples,
).images

images.insert(0, image)

for idx, img in enumerate(images):
    img.save(f"output/output_image_{idx}.png")

